# Bind a property of a selfmade user control to a property of the main-view-model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a wpf application where I extended the RichTextBox to provide some specific functions. Lets call that new class BetterTextBox.

Now, when I click in that TextBox TextBox.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp is called and I am getting the CaretPosition:

```
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        PressedOffset = Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(CaretPosition);      
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedOffsetProperty 
          = DependencyProperty.Register("PressedOffset", typeof(int),
            typeof(ByteViewTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            DefaultValue = 0,
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
        });

    public int PressedOffset
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PressedOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressedOffsetProperty, value); Console.WriteLine("klöjgf");}
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow">
    <BetterTextBox />
</Window>
```

MainWindow has MainViewModel as DataContext. What I want to do is, when a MouseClick in BetterTextBox occurs, a function in MainViewModel should be called. How can I get out of my UserControl a call a function in the MainViewModel?

I tried something like this:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow">
   <BetterTextBox PressedOffset="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=MyFunction"/>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public int MyFunction
{
     set { callMyRealFunction(); }
}
```

But that doesn't work. There is also a way to register a CallbackFunction for PressedOffsetProperty, but I am not sure how to register there a function from the MainViewModel which is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Create another dependency property of type ICommand say 'TextClickCommand'.
Create a command in your viewmodel and bind to TextClickCommand and execute this on MouseClick.

Edit:
You can do it even the other way around create a IsTextSelected bool dependency property in textbox bind to this bool using a propery in view model and call your method in view model property setter.

Comment: Sry, I can't really follow you. Can you be more precisly? I am already doing your "Edit" without luck or not? I also googled for Commands and there is a bunch of results and I am getting lost.